# navigate and navigateByUrl not navigating to the page

Tags: angular

My app doesn't navigate to a new page. When I include `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in my app.component.html, it shows the check-out component so I know that it's routing to the right URL but I want to navigate to a new page, not stay on the same page.

In shopping-cart.component.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule(
{
   imports:[
       RouterModule
   ]
}
)
public checkOut(): void {

this.router.navigate(['check-out'], {relativeTo: this.route});

//this.router.navigateByUrl('/check-out/check-out');
}
ngOnInit(): void {
this.submitForm = new FormGroup({ 
}); 
}
```

In app-routing.module.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CheckOutComponent } from './check-out/check-out.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{
   path: 'check-out',
   component: CheckOutComponent
   }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})


export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In app.module.ts

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CheckOutComponent } from './check-out/check-out.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ShoppingCartComponent } from './shopping-cart/shopping-cart.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CheckOutComponent,
    ShoppingCartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
     RouterModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }


constructor(public router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}
```

shopping-cart.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="submitForm" (ngSubmit)="checkOut()">
<input type="submit" value="Check Out">
</form>
```

Comment: your app-routing.module only have path `check-out`

Comment: new page means new window?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

````
Add ```<router-outlet></ router-outlet>``` in app.component.html if not added.

public checkOut(): void {
   this.router.navigate(['/check-out'], {relativeTo: this.route}); // add slash before route path.
}
````

Comment: When I add <router-outlet></ router-outlet>, it displays the page in the same window and doesn't navigate to a new page.